# Use Fastlane with Flutter on Bitrise

Tags: flutter, fastlane, bitrise

I have integrated Fastlane to my Flutter code base with separate Fastfiles for iOS and Android. It works well on my local machine. Now I am trying to automate the same on Bitrise. Is it possible to so? I could find official Bitrise guides for deploying Flutter apps and for integrating Fastlane, but not for case that includes both. Can anyone help ?

Comment: Does this document help you? https://devcenter.bitrise.io/getting-started/getting-started-with-flutter-apps/

Comment: I had read this article. It describes the case where there is no Fastlane. In my case, I already have a working setup with Fastlane, including authenticating with the AppStore. I was hoping to reuse the same on Bitrise.

Comment: You can always call fastlane from script step in your workflow. https://www.bitrise.io/integrations/steps/script

Comment: Thanks @ŁukaszŁabuński. I got it working. I will post an answer when I get some time.